# Load data from yaml using dedicated class in pytest-bdd in step file(@given, @when, @then)

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, bdd, pytest-bdd

How to resolve problem with catching data from yaml in steps.py in pytest-bdd. In other part of framework, everything works as it should. I have class:

```
class Globals:
    TITLE = None
    USERNAME1 = None
    LAST_NAME1 = None
    PASSWORD1 = None
    WRONG_PASSWORD = None
    EMAIL1 = None
    BDAY = None
    BMONTH = None
    BYEAR = None

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.load_data_from_yaml(path)

    def load_data_from_yaml(self, path):
        with open(path, "r") as param_file:
            try:
                yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(param_file)
                self.TITLE = yaml_file.get("title1")
                self.USERNAME1 = yaml_file.get("username1")
                self.PASSWORD1 = yaml_file.get("password1")
                self.WRONG_PASSWORD = yaml_file.get("wrong_password")
                self.LAST_NAME1 = yaml_file.get("lastname1")
                self.EMAIL1 = yaml_file.get("email1")
                self.BDAY = yaml_file.get("bday")
                self.BMONTH = yaml_file.get("bmonth")
                self.BYEAR = yaml_file.get("byear")


            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)

    def get_yaml_element(self, element):
        return getattr(self, element, None)
```

and scenario:

```
  Scenario Outline: Login to the website
    Given Navigate to login page
    When I enter my login and "<password>"
    And I click the login button
    Then I should get login alert

    Examples:
      | password        |
      | PASSWORD1       |
      | WRONG_PASSWORD  |
```

and step:

```
@when('I enter my login and <password>')
def step_when_enter_credentials(webdriver_initializer, password):
    driver = webdriver_initializer
    selenium_elements = Page(driver)
    globals_instance = Globals(PARAMS_PATH)
    password_to_use = globals_instance.get_yaml_element(password)
    selenium_elements.type_into(selenium_elements.EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGISTER_VALUE, selenium_elements.globals.EMAIL1)
    selenium_elements.type_into(selenium_elements.EMAIL_PASSWORD, password_to_use)
```

besides steps.py `globals_instance` work as it should be but in this situation i still have an error:

```
E   pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: When "I enter my login and "PASSWORD1"". Line 12 in scenario "Login to the website" in the feature "pytest_bdd/features/login.feature"
All traceback entries are hidden. Pass `--full-trace` to see hidden and internal frames.
```

My question is why?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: step `@when('I enter my login and {password}')` should have parse `@when(parsers.parse('I enter my login and {password}'))`